# Completely Uninstall Visual Studio, multiple versions

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 machine where VS 2013 and VS 2017 had already been installed long ago. VS 2019 is acting very flaky (can't compile a nearly pristine C++ project) so I'd like to scrub all traces of any VS from my computer and start with a fresh install of VS2019 only.
The Visual Studio Installer only wants to add software. How can I safely wipe all the installations of Visual Studio entirely off my system so that I can get a clean install? `Add/Remove Programs` shows I have dozens of Microsoft products installed; it's not at all clear to me which ones should be removed to accomplish my goal.

Comment: More -> Uninstall

Comment: If all else fails, see [`InstallCleanup.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you can try the following methods to uninstall VS.

1. Open the `Visual Studio Installer` and select `Uninstall`.
   [image]

2.To remove all installations of `Visual Studio` and the `Visual Studio Installer` from your machine, uninstall it from Apps & Features.

2.1 In Windows 10, type Apps and Features in the "Type here to search" box.

2.2 Find Visual Studio which you want to uninstall.

2.3 Choose Uninstall.

2.4 Then, find Microsoft Visual Studio Installer.

2.5 Choose Uninstall.

3. You could run [InstallCleanup.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to delete remove all files. I suggest you use this method last.

3.1 Close the Visual Studio Installer.

3.2 Open an administrator command prompt. To open an administrator command prompt, follow these steps:

- Type cmd in the "Type here to search" box.
- Right-click Command Prompt, and then choose Run as administrator.

3.3 Enter the full path of the InstallCleanup.exe tool and add the command-line switch you prefer. By default, the path of the tool is as follows. The double quotes enclose a command containing spaces:

Copy

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"
```

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: Location of InstallCleanup.exe `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if vs2013 uses the same installation framework but vs2017 can be uninstalled through the program that runs if you select Tools -> Get Tools and Features from the vs2019 menu. With the most recent update of that installer program you do have to hit the close button to leave the vs2019 workflow/individual feature installation selection screen.

Once you are back at the main screen you should be able to select the 'More' button for versions you wish to uninstall to get an Uninstall option.

Note that in any case you do not wish to *completely* uninstall VS. For example, regardless of what else you do you want to leave versions of the VC runtime in case there are programs linked against it.

Comment: I do intend to reinstall it so I would think the runtime would come along with a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

from Visual studio installer all the Visual studio version will be visible from there click on more drop down and uninstall them wherever applicable.

[image: From visual studio]